# SKScene frozen when updating UIKit components

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uikit, skscene

I'm working on a game using Swift and SpriteKit. I have a ViewController that has a SKView for the scene/game and a UILabel for the score. For some reason, whenever I update the UILabel text on my ViewController, my scene freezes and does not update.

Here is the code I have to communicate between my ViewController and my Scene

```
protocol ControllerDelegate {
   updateScore(score: Int)
}

class ViewController: ControllerDelegate {
     @IBOutlet var gameView: SKView!
     @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

     func viewDidAppear() {
         let scene = GameScene()
         scene.delegate = self
         self.gameView.presentScene(scene)
     }

     func updateScore(score: Int) {
         self.scoreLabel.text = "SCORE: \(score)"
     }
}
```

Whenever I call `delegate.updateScore` in my GameScene, it freezes.

Comment: After some more fiddling, it seems like my scene only freezes when I change the text of the scoreLabel. If i change the background color of the label, or change the background color of the view in the ViewController, the scene doesn't freeze.

Comment: Are you using a custom font by any chance? Heard that might have some impact.

Comment: No, I am not using custom font.